# How to popup window on incoming call screen like truecaller in PhoneGap Android app

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

In my application I want to open a window with caller name like Truecaller for incoming/outgoing call in PhoneGap for android application. I mean when I get call or outgoing call, I want to open a pop up window even when my application is closed.

My Code

```
// Enable background mode
cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();

// Called when background mode has been activated
cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.onactivate = function() {


    setInterval(function() {

        PhoneCallTrap.onCall(function(state) {
            console.log("CHANGE STATE: " + state);
            if (state == "RINGING") {
                var now = new Date().getTime(),
                    _5_sec_from_now = new Date(now + 1 * 1000);
                var sound = device.platform == 'Android' ? 'file://sound.mp3' : 'file://beep.caf';
                cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
                    id: 1,
                    title: 'Call',
                    text: 'Test Message 1',
                    at: _5_sec_from_now,
                    sound: sound,
                    badge: 12
                });
            }
        });

    }, 1000);
}
```

But it is not working when my app is closed.

Comment: Please show what did you tried so far?

Comment: @Maňish Yadav: Did you vote minus ?

Comment: I didn't ... read this [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haved solve this issue using following steps

1) Add these permissions in **AndroiMainFest.xml**

```
<receiver android:name=".PhoneStateReceiver" android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
       <intent-filter android:exported="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
       </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

2) Create **PhoneStateReceiver.java**

```
public class PhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Intent Detected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // This is where you start your service        

        try {
            System.out.println("Receiver start");
            String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

            if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Incoming Call State", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Ringing State Number is -" + incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if ((state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK))) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Call Received State", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Call Idle State", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

3) Add in **MainActivity.java**

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
        Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) !=
    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {} else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            new String[] {
                Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
            },
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
    }
}
```

4) You can on permission in setting > App > Your App > permission **OR** On programtically

**Reference Link:** **http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/detecting-incoming-phone-calls-in-android**

Comment: you ended up going native? no success with ionic? I'm trying to do the same thing

Comment: the code you wrote is Java. How do I add that into my project?

Comment: I just need a clearer direction of how to go about this. Thanks

Comment: For step 1 add above code as shown in step 1. In stet 2 create PhoneStateReceiver.java and add above code for this and in step 3 import PhoneStateReceiver.java file in MainActivity.java add above code and also add all require class.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry one last clarification, I am to add this in the `platforms/android` directory right?